# Check if Word document closed from Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I'm performing several prints of embedded Word document witch has some fields linked to some cells, by my `PrintOut` macro, in a `For..Next` loop, as below.

I need after each print task, that the program wait for document to close and then doing the next print.

In this situation I receive error. Can anyone help ?

```
Sub contract()

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 100
    Cells(Sheets("SheetName").ListObjects("StaffInfo").ListRows.Count + 9, 8).Value = i

    General.PrintIt ("EmbeddedDoc") 'Doc has many linked fields

Next i

End Sub
```

Print method

```
Sub PrintIt(P As String)
Dim objWord As Object
Dim ObjDoc As Object
Dim Oshp As Object

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ActiveSheet.OLEObjects(P).Activate
Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = False

Set ObjDoc = objWord.ActiveDocument

ObjDoc.Fields.Update
For Each Oshp In ObjDoc.Content.ShapeRange
    Oshp.TextFrame.TextRange.Fields.Update
Next

ObjDoc.PrintOut Background:=False
ObjDoc.PrintOut

objWord.Quit SaveChanges:=False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub 'Print it
```

Comment: What error do you get?  And on which line do you get it?

Comment: What happens if you add `DoEvents` after the line `objWord.Quit SaveChanges:=False`

Comment: Error: Run-time error '5479: you cannot close Microsoft Word because a dialog box is open. Click OK, switch to word, and then close the dialog box. after that this error shown: Microsoft Word has encountered a problem and need to close. ... send error report, dont send. and Word window closed. but excel is open and this line shown as error: 'ObjDoc.PrintOut Background:=False' in VBA.

Comment: When I controlled macro running by a msgbox, by pressing OK cmdbotton immediately, this error was shown in Word application that has no documents: "the margin of section 1 are outside the printable area of the page. ... " Why this error throws? when I pressing "Ok" slow, documents printing is done without issue.  thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Introduced problem was solved by this code.
Above code do open and close embedded word document, 100 times, and that problem was happening in close document.
Exactly, I cant understand why closing document immediately after printout command that where after open and update fields,  generating that error.
Thus I cleaned the problem ask!
By integrating "PrintIt" method in "Contract" method that is parent of that, without calling "PrintIt" for each document printout, embedded document opens each one, perform doc links updating and printing 100 times in for next loop and close word app and document, at last, each one too.

In short, I cant find reason of problem in several Open-Print-Close document in order immediately; But i change the algorithm to Open-Several print-Close and problem been cleaned!

```
Sub contract()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("SheetName").Unprotect

'Declare variables
Dim i As Integer
Dim objWord, ObjDoc As Object

'Core
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("Contract").Activate
Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = False

Set ObjDoc = objWord.ActiveDocument

For i = 1 To 100

    Cells(x, y).Value = i 'A specific cell that
' word embedded document fields are linked to 
'corresponding fields they values change 
'by changing this cell.
    ObjDoc.Fields.Update

    ObjDoc.PrintOut Background:=False
    ObjDoc.PrintOut

Next i
objWord.Quit SaveChanges:=False
Sheets("SheetName").Protect AllowFiltering:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: Of course                                                                                                                             ................